# Python help displaying strings

Tags: python

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter your name, eg Zelle: ")
    name = name.lower()
    output = []
    for character in name:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        output.append(number)

    print(output)


main()
```

This is what I have so far but I need to make this program run each of the letter in the name a display the output like this:

```
Enter a name (eg, Zelle): Zelle
Letter Z value is 26
Letter e value is 5
Letter l value is 12
Letter l value is 12
Letter e value is 5
The numeric value of the name 'Zelle' is 60
```

And honestly Im not to sure how to do that

Comment: A tip: Instead of appending number to list, try to use `print` function and string formatting (ex `%`).

Comment: I tried whats up there but Im newish to programming so Im not really sure how to go about fixing it

Comment: @Nf4r 5  Your comment hellped me so much thank you, dont know why I didnt do this in the first place. Went the long way around instead

Comment: No problem. I think it's always better to give a tip to someone who is still learning. You will be fine.

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter your name, eg Zelle: ")
    name = name.lower()
    output = []
    name_value = 0
    for character in name:
        number = ord(character) - 96
        output.append((character,number))
        print("Letter {} value is {}".format(character, number))
        name_value += number
    print("The numeric value of the name: {} is {}".format(name, name_value))

main()
```

edited :)

Comment: You could've used `sum` instead of the second loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
name = input("Enter your name, eg Zelle: ")
name = name.lower()
output = []
total = 0
for character in name:
    number = ord(character) - 96
    total += number
    print("Letter {0} value is {1}".format(character, number))
print("The numeric value of the name {0} is {1}".format(name, total))


main()
```

This is what I have now and it works perfectly thank you everyone.

Answer (score 0):

```
def main():
    name = input("Enter your name, eg Zelle:").lower()
    char_values = [ord(char) for char in name]
    total = sum(char_values)
    for value in char_values:
        print("Letter {} value is {}".format(chr(value), value))
    print("The numeric value of the name {} is {}".format(name, total))

main()
```